# Oracle: Delete statement becomes very slow when using variable

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle12c

I have an Oracle procedure that normally takes around 5 minutes to run. There are two areas in the procedure where I need to query a list of id numbers that may have been modified. The query in these two segments is identical. The first is at the beginning of a cursor definition, and the second is in a delete statement in the main body of the procedure. The key part that is repeated a lot involves getting the most recent date a certain table was refreshed. The entire procedure is fairly lengthy, so I'll include only the relevant bits below.

Here is the beginning of the cursor:

```
cursor gvg_profile_c is
     
with last_refreshed as
  (select trunc(max(t.last_refreshed)) as max_date
     from ad.pbi_gvg_profile t),
      
with modified_ids as
 (
        
  select distinct id_number
    from ad.hr_giving cg
    join ad.pbi_dates d
      on d.DATE_FULL = trunc(cg.processed_date)
   where d.RELATIVE_DATE >= (select max_date from last_refreshed)
     and d.RELATIVE_DATE <= trunc(CURRENT_DATE)
     and cg.fiscal_year >= ad.current_fiscal_year - 6
        
  union
        
  select distinct gi.gift_donor_id as id_number
    from ad.gift gi
   where gi.date_added >= (select max_date from last_refreshed)
      or gi.date_modified >= (select max_date from last_refreshed)
        
  union
        
  select distinct p.pledge_donor_id as id_number
    from ad.pledge_rev p
   where p.date_added >= (select max_date from last_refreshed)
      or p.date_modified >= (select max_date from last_refreshed)
        
  union
        
  select distinct a.id_number
    from ad.affiliation a
   where a.date_added >= (select max_date from last_refreshed)
      or a.date_modified >= (select max_date from last_refreshed)
        
  ),
```

Here is the delete statment:

```
delete from ad.pbi_gvg_profile p
  where p.id_number in
        (with last_refreshed as (select trunc(max(t.last_refreshed)) as max_date
            from ad.pbi_gvg_profile t)
          select distinct id_number
            from ad.hr_giving cg
            join ad.pbi_dates d
              on d.DATE_FULL = trunc(cg.processed_date)
           where d.RELATIVE_DATE >= (select max_date from last_refreshed)
             and d.RELATIVE_DATE <= trunc(CURRENT_DATE)
             and cg.fiscal_year >= ad.current_fiscal_year - 6
          
          union
          
          select distinct gi.gift_donor_id as id_number
            from ad.gift gi
           where gi.date_added >= (select max_date from last_refreshed)
              or gi.date_modified >= (select max_date from last_refreshed)
          
          union
          
          select distinct p.pledge_donor_id as id_number
            from ad.pledge_rev p
           where p.date_added >= (select max_date from last_refreshed)
              or p.date_modified >= (select max_date from last_refreshed)
          
          union
          
          select distinct a.id_number
            from ad.affiliation a
           where a.date_added >= (select max_date from last_refreshed)
              or a.date_modified >= (select max_date from last_refreshed)
         );
```

I thought it would make more sense and be more efficient to a have a function that calculates the last_refreshed date and puts it in a variable that can be reused. So I did that. Here's the function:

NOTE: You can see here that I sometimes need to get the date from a different table. That is accounted for for the above code via an if/else, I just left it out so you don't have to read identical code 4 times.

```
  function get_last_refreshed_date(scope in smallint) return date is
    
  last_refreshed date;
  table_name varchar2(30);
  select_sql varchar2(255);
  
  begin

  if scope = c_scope_all then
    table_name := 'ad.pbi_gvg_profile';
  else
    table_name := 'ad.pbi_gvg_profile_ag';
  end if;
  select_sql := 'select trunc(max(last_refreshed))
                 from '||table_name;
         
                 
  execute immediate select_sql 
  into last_refreshed;

  
  return(last_refreshed);
  
  end get_last_refreshed_date;
```

Then I change the beginning of my cursor to use this function and a variable instead, so now it looks like this:

```
last_refreshed  date := get_last_refreshed_date(scope);

cursor gvg_profile_c is

with modified_ids as
 (
        
  select distinct id_number
    from ad.hr_giving cg
    join ad.pbi_dates d
      on d.DATE_FULL = trunc(cg.processed_date)
   where d.RELATIVE_DATE >= last_refreshed
     and d.RELATIVE_DATE <= trunc(CURRENT_DATE)
     and cg.fiscal_year >= ad.current_fiscal_year - 6
        
  union
        
  select distinct gi.gift_donor_id as id_number
    from ad.gift gi
   where gi.date_added >= last_refreshed
      or gi.date_modified >= last_refreshed
        
  union
        
  select distinct p.pledge_donor_id as id_number
    from ad.pledge_rev p
   where p.date_added >= last_refreshed
      or p.date_modified >= last_refreshed
        
  union
        
  select distinct a.id_number
    from ad.affiliation a
   where a.date_added >= last_refreshed
      or a.date_modified >= last_refreshed
        
  ),
```

This works fine. My procedure still only takes 5 minutes to run.

However, when I make the same identical change to the Delete statement, suddenly the procedure takes about 65 minutes to run. And I can tell from logging that the execution of the delete statement accounts for over 60 of those minutes.

Why would the variable work fine in the cursor, but cause a major slowdown in a delete statement in the body of the procedure?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm afraid the DELETE operation changes the plan dramatically - you cannot expect the same plan to be used for a SELECT and a DELETE, even for subqueries. The only way to solve your issue is to do normal SQL tuning, which as always requires that you examine the explain plain, ASH data (v$active_session_history) to see where it is spending all its time, and then determine what hints you may need to correct the plan.

Comment: As a side note : Using those `distinct id_number` along with `union` operator has no sense, indeed `union`s should already be replaced with `union all`s as following an `IN` operator and stated within a subquery. This also would degrade the performance of the query.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Ah, you are definitely right. In the cursor I can remove the distinct, and in the delete sub query I can also switch to union all. Thanks!

Comment: Get an active SQL Monitor report; that will tell you where time is being spent in the execution